# jmeter - How to make loop and have to change the value each and every time

Tags: loops, jmeter, execution

My concern is about to make a loop based on the no of values which I captured in the response, and want to execute the that..

I will explain in detailed.

> thread 1: abc.com --which gives a response as
>
> ```
>     1.def.com/abcd,
>     2.def.com/cdef,
>     3.def.com/hagd
> ```

Here I want to capture no of files and have to pass the values in a loop in the next thread.

> thread 2: ip=def.com and the path will change as we have in the above
>   response and how many responses are there in thread
>
> ```
>       1 that many times thread 
>       2 have to execute with changing the path as the no of values in the first response.
> ```

Hope u understand my concern. Help me out of it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass values from one sampler response to the next sampler and the next sampler should iterate based on the variable received in the previous response. You can use For Each in you scenario.

In the below, I am getting all the values from the regular expression in variable "inputValues" and taking them out using output variable "returnVal". Now, returnVal is going to give the val=1,2,3.
[image]

Below you can see, first sampler executed one time, from its response i got 3 values using regular expression. Then, using For Each, I can send 2nd request for 3 times and can supply the value also to the 2nd request using "returnVal"
[image]

Hope this help.

Comment: hi sunny I think Its work better but not much actually... and what the variable name you used in regex.. and I need to change the path of next thread with respect to no of values I got. need more explanation

Comment: @biyyapu if it helped you can accept the answer,see stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: and I need more info on this.. i have response as abc.com/image_abc/1234_1270*780.jpg  from this i have to capture 1234 only . can u help for this .

Comment: Use, regular expression extractor and use it to extract the required values. Create a regular expression for this like "image_abc/(.+?)_" , template $1$ and Match No:- "1" (for all) and fetch the values.

Comment: If it helps then you can accept as an answer to help others. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers